# Validate Email Using "Hidden Form"?

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I want to use HTML5's `type="email"` validation to create a function for validating emails.

What I'd like to do, if possible, is to create a form, and attach an input whose `type="email"` so that I can try to submit it. I can then see if it worked or not to return whether or not the email passed is in fact an email.

Something like this, but I know this doesn't work:

```
function isEmail (string) {
    var frm   = document.createElement('form');
    var input = document.createElement('input');

    input.setAttribute('type', 'email');
    input.setAttribute('action', 'javascript:void(0)');
    input.setAttribute('value', string);

    frm.appendChild(input);

    // I know this doesn't work
    if ( !! frm.submit() ) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

**Is it possible to validate an email address in this way?**

Comment: Generic disclaimer: the syntactical validity of an email address does not imply that the email address actually exists. So don't try to go overboard with this. All you should want to do is catch typos from the user, actual verification requires an email with a link or passcode or something.

Comment: For sure, I'm just trying to make sure that the email passed is syntactically correct.

Comment: Well on the point of "syntactical correctness", see the Note under the second link I posted: _"This requirement is a willful violation of RFC 5322, which defines a syntax for e-mail addresses that is simultaneously too strict (before the "@" character), too vague (after the "@" character), and too lax (allowing comments, whitespace characters, and quoted strings in manners unfamiliar to most users) to be of practical use here."_ - so _definitions_ on what constitutes a "valid" email address differ already, depending on who you ask. Checking less strictly than necessary is usually advisable.

Comment: In addition to CBroe's comment above, you should also be extremely circumspect about what the term "email address" refers to. You may be surprised by the number of different things this can refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#e-mail-state-(type=email) says,

> User agents may allow the user to set the value to a string that is not a valid e-mail address

so I probably would rather not rely on that.

Plus, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address has a (JS compatible) regular expression that performs the same check, as the browser is supposed to when validating an email input field – so I'd probably just use that instead.

---

But, should you insist on using a form field for this – HTML5 also provides an API to check if form fields are valid, see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api - so there is no need to actually submit the form.

I have not checked browser compatibility for input type=email – but with the regex solution you'll have something that should work in every browser, whereas if you rely on HTML5 it might fail in some that have not yet caught up.

Comment: I like this answer, and I'll use this regex in my product. I'm still curious about my bolded question, though: is what I'm trying to do *possible*, albeit not recommended?

Comment: See my edit - HTML5 also specifies an API to check form fields for validity.

Comment: Yeah, just saw it. Waiting a few minutes so I can mark as correct